# How to use lupdate with @lst-file argument?

Tags: qt, qt-linguist

I want to run the *lupdate* tool of *Qt-Linguist* for a list of TS files. I want to give that list from a file and not from explicit command arguments.

This is the help of the command :

> Usage:
>
> ```
> lupdate [options] [project-file]...
> lupdate [options] [source-file|path|@lst-file]... -ts ts-files|@lst-file
> ```
>
> ```
> @lst-file
>      Read additional file names (one per line) or includepaths (one per
>      line, and prefixed with -I) from lst-file.
> ```

I GUESS the argument `@list-file` is exactly what I need but I do not know how to use it. I tried to give a file containing the names of my TS files but I get this error :

```
 $ lupdate.exe source -ts translations/language-list.txt
 Scanning directory 'source'...
 lupdate error: File 'translations/language-list.txt' has no recognized extension.
```

I tried with .txt, .lst, no extension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the "@" as shown in the help file. Assuming as an example you have a source QML file called main.qml and an lst-file called file.txt which contains these lines:

```
lang_de.ts
lang_en.ts
lang_fr.ts
```

Then you use lupdate like this:

```
lupdate main.qml -ts @file.txt
```

And it will create the three files which you can now use in Linguist.